# Xubuntu 14.04 Ignoring Screen Layout Changes

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, xubuntu, xserver

I have two screens of different sizes on an old nvidia card.  When I login the smaller (left-side) screen aligns to the top of the larger screen.  I want to align it to the bottom but changing the nvidia settings has no effect:

## Initial Settings

[image]

## After Editing

[image]

Note that I have also changed the "primary" screen to the larger display.

## No Effect

If I click `Apply` then reopen the settings, my changes are gone.

If I click `Save to X Configuration File`, my changes are saved to the conf file but have no effect, even after restarting the X server.

## Update

Running the nvidia settings from the command line:

```
gksudo nvidia-settings &
```

gave me the following when I clicked `Apply`:

```
The program 'nvidia-settings' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'.
  (Details: serial 612 error_code 2 request_code 158 minor_code 25)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Job 1, “gksudo nvidia-settings &” has ended
```

Adding that info to this question has caused AskUbuntu to suggest some interesting related questions that suggest that changing my nvidia drivers might help.  Now I just need to work out how to do that without breaking something.

Comment: the `update` you wrote it's just a bug in previous nvidia drivers versions, did you run `xrandr` to see what primarly and connected is default `screen0` for example if your other display named `screen1` try to edit `sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` you'll see the default `screen` identifier for server layout and device section.